# Cocos2d structure and navigation

Tags: c#, ios, wpf, xna, cocos2d-x-for-xna

Cocos 2d xna c#.

I'm using windows tamplate.
I have next classes Programm, Game1, AppDelegate, IntroLayer, MainLayer.
Programm, Game1, AppDelegate - I understand that it's begin and settings, like resolution, touch and ect.
From AppDelegate we run and Draw IntroLayer. 'Layer', it's like (.xaml +.xaml.cs) file in wpf?
In IntroLayer i want to lisen mouse and keyboard, but `public override void Update(float dt)` don't listen.
I only listen in `Update method in Game1 class`.

I search cocos2d tutorials, but found little. This's tutorial good [link](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/cocos2d_xna/cocos2dxna_tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my questions.
I need to add this code in my layer to get Update method.

```
    public override bool Init()
    {
        ScheduleUpdate();
        return base.Init();
    }

    public override void Update(float dt)
    {
         base.Update(dt);
    }
```

I found it this: [link to stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413386/layer-update-does-not-get-called-in-cocos2d-iphone)